# Randomizing in all possible combinations in Python

Tags: python, list, random, psychopy

Here is my code:

```
if condition == '1':
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist1/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '2':
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist1/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '3':
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist1/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '4':
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist1/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '5':
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist1/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '6':
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist1/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '7':
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '8':
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '9':
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '10':
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist4/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '11':
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist4/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '12':
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '13':
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '14':
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '15':
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '16':
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist4/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '17':
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist4/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '18':
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '19':
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '20':
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '21':
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '22':
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist4/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '23':
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist4/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
elif condition == '24':
    e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*")
    b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    d = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*")
    a = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*")
    c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")
```

Basically what this does it is draws from a different list based on all combinations of a,c,d,e and makes a and b correspond. This code works fine, but it isn't very beautiful. I was wondering if anyone had any advice I do the same thing in fewer lines of code. More than anything I'm just trying to expand my knowledge of writing code, so if you know there is a more eloquent way of writing this let me know. :)

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hmmm ... by my count, there should be 120 permutations of 5 items (taken 5 at a time)... You only seem to have 24.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'd love to help on this, but the pattern is too unclear. You're swapping both the order of the variables and their data. Organize your data better and it will be easier to see the pattern.

Comment: In some of your conditions, the values for a and b are *identical* and not just *related* (9, 12 and 15 for example) - why?

Comment: Ever heard of lists?

Comment: You have tagged psychopy, yet the code does not contain any use of the psychopy module. Consider removing that tag.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you meant by "make a and b correspond", but maybe this would work:

```
from itertools import permutations
from random import choice

globs = [glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*"),
         glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist1/*"),
         glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*"),
         glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*"),
         glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*")]

glob_permutations = list(permutations(globs))

a, b, c, d, e = choice(glob_permutations)
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library has a function for [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) without repetitions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import itertools
import glob

p = [
    glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist1/*"),
    glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist4/*"),
    glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist2/*"),
    glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist3/*"),
    glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist4/*"),
]

perm = itertools.permutations(p)

print(len(perm))
```

=> 120 permutations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that?

```
setup = {'1': ('1','1','2','3','4'),
         '2': ('1','1','2','3','4'),
        #...
        }
a = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist" + setup[condition][0] + "/*")
b = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist" + setup[condition][1] + "/*")
c = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist" + setup[condition][2] + "/*")
d = glob.glob("DDtest/distractorimagelist" + setup[condition][3] + "/*")
e = glob.glob("DDtest/targetimagelist" + setup[condition][4] + "/*")
```

Comment: Seems like you're just moving the problem from one spot to another.

Comment: Does it? It makes for much shorter code, and I don't see how you could avoid listing it alltogether. Either that or I'm not seeing the connection between the condition and the combination.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's a connection we're not seeing because the question is not entirely clear.